# How to check parameter type in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Maybe I'm going overboard on validations, but I want to make sure when I get a POST request, it contains specific specific values (could be done through params.require()), and that these values are of a specific type: hash, array, string. TBH, I'm not even certain of all the types that can be transmitted via a POST request. Problem is, the objects are showing up as type ActionController::Parameters when using .is_a? If there is a better way to do this in rails, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Rails (or more precisely Rack) can parse both arrays and hashes out of the parameters which are created through the `name` attribute.

For example:

```
# simple hash
user[email]="test@example.com"

# nested hash
user[address][street]="Easy Street 21" 

# an array with 3 elements
user[some_arrray_param][]="1" 
user[some_arrray_param][]="2" 
user[some_arrray_param][]="3"
```

When you get a key containing a "hash" from the parameters with `.require` or `.fetch` they actually return an `ActionController::Parameters` instance which is a hash like object but features the Rails strong parameters interface among other things.

`.require()` just gets a hash key and raises an exception if its not present.

What you´re trying to do though is really something that should be handled on the model level through validations instead of making your controllers fat.

Comment: Thanks. My models are already fat, and this is going to go in a special helper. Really I want to stop execution before it gets to the model with invalid types, missing params, etc. The other attributes like length, permitted values, and presence_required should go in the model. Still, I am looking for a way to call is_a? on the parameter hash value.

Comment: Use duck typing instead.

Comment: Duck typing may be the way to go here. In this particular case, I'm resorting to this because of the design of the framework, but I know that duck typing is a pretty standard methodology... why would you use duck typing over is_a?(Hash) or object.class == Hash? I understand you may just need to run a particular method which could be valid on several different objects but that seems dangerous and likely to get you something you're not expecting.